# How to explain this operator associativity?

Tags: java, associativity

According to [this table](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~guvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html), `++` has right to left associativity. So, I run this code:

```
int a = 5;
++a + ++a * ++a
```

and expect the expression to be `50` (as `8 + 7 * 6`, increment starts from right to left). But the expression is evaluated from left to right (`6 + 7 * 8`) by Eclipse, and gives result as `62`. I am new to this associativity in Java, and must be missing something obvious. Please help me understand this strange behavior.

**EDIT:** Thank you for your answers, but I have one more question now. It is that, as seen from @bizclop's code and tree answer, it is obvious that the associativity for `++` doesn't matter. Then, is there *any* use case for this associativity of `++`/`--`?

Comment: Associativity != precedence. Precedence comes first, associativity is only used to resolve cases where the operators have the same precedence.

Comment: I can't think of an example where the associativity of the `++`/`--` operators matters, there probably isn't one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two different things mixed up here: expression parsing and expression evaluation.

Let's start with the expression: `++a + ++a * ++a`. What do we first have to do with it? Since operators `+` and `*` need two operands and `++` needs one, we have to figure out which operand goes with which operation. This is the expression parsing step, where precedence/associativity are applied.

1. `++` has the highest precedence, so we can rewrite our expression as `(++a) + (++a) * (++a)`
2. Next up it's `*`, so again we can add parentheses: `(++a) + ((++a) * (++a))`
3. And lastly we have `+`, the lowest precedence of all, so for the sake of symmetry we can write:  `((++a) + ((++a) * (++a)))`

Note that we can represent this neatly as a tree:

```
   +
  / \
++   *
 |   | \
 a  ++ ++
     |  |
     a  a
```

So this is our evaluation tree based on precedence and associativity.

> Note that in this case associativity didn't matter at all as all the operators
>   had different precedence. Had our expression been `4 - 1 - 3 + 2`, it
>   would've been important to use associativity to reach `(((4 - 1) - 3) + 2)`, as `+` and `-` have the same precedence.

Now comes the next step, evaluation. Evaluation **always** happens from left to right (even for assignments, though the rules are a bit quirky), but it happens left-to-right using the tree we've just built.

1. So first of all we start evaluating the `+` operator, as it's on the top.
2. We then go one level down to the left, as we evaluate the `++a` on the left side of the `+` operator, *(6)*
3. then we go to the right and start evaluating the `*` operation.
4. The way we do it is to evaluate the second `++a`, *(7)*
5. then the third `++a` *(8)*
6. and then we multiply the result of steps 4 and 5 (this is the `*` operation evaluated), *(56)*
7. and finally we add the result of step 6 to the result of step 2 *(62)*

...and we're done.

**TL;DR**: Precedence and associativity determine where to put parentheses but evaluation is always left-to-right.

> [15.7. Evaluation Order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7)
>
> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right.

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I needed. I will always evaluate all expressions using this tree method!

Comment: I have one more query, I edited the question for that. Please see.

Answer (score 3):

**It is because multiplication operator `*` has higher precedence over the addition `+` operator.**

The computation will be `++a + (++a * ++a) = 6 + 7 * 8`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have one more query, I edited the question for that. Please see.